# Is it possible to close a quick action modal (lightning component) when clicking anywhere outside the modal

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, quickaction

I have read a bunch of answers regarding how to close a modal dialog when closing anywhere else. My scenario is the modal is the salesforce quick action opened lightning component. It is an aura component embedding an lwc. I am wondering whether it is possible to close that modal dialog when clicking anywhere else since I can't actually implement that quick action modal?

Comment: According to the standard styles, the slds-modal's z-index is 9001, the back-drop''s z-index is 9000, so you will not be able to capture the click event of back-drop. [I have read a bunch of answers regarding how to close a modal dialog when closing anywhere else] -> could you show me some of them? Maybe those will help.

Comment: @Lanjinest like these ones: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/188623/close-lightning-modal-by-clicking-anywhere-outside-of-it and https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/311851/prevent-lwc-modal-from-closing-when-clicking-anywhere-outside-it?rq=1